# How can I install selenium chrome driver in jenkins?

Tags: selenium, docker, jenkins, containers, selenium-chromedriver

I have pulled jenkins container which exposes jenkins at port 8080 in my localhost.

I can see jenkins running fine.
I have installed pip
I have installed selenium with pip
and when I run the test I get an Error:

```
+ python /var/jenkins_home/workspace/My_Job/slenium_login.py
12:02:06 Traceback (most recent call last):

12:02:06   File "/var/jenkins_home/workspace/My_Job/slenium_login.py", line 6, in <module>

12:02:06     driver = webdriver.Chrome(cd)

12:02:06   File "/var/jenkins_home/shiningpanda/jobs/5db0e2cb/virtualenvs/d41d8cd9/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 62, in __init__

12:02:06     self.service.start()

12:02:06   File "/var/jenkins_home/shiningpanda/jobs/5db0e2cb/virtualenvs/d41d8cd9/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 81, in start

12:02:06     os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)

12:02:06 selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

How can I install selenium chrome driver in my jenkins environment?

Comment: just download the chromdriver executable and put it somewhere. if it's linux make sure it's accessible using jenkins user.

Comment: @GaurangShah I am new to jenkins. I am running jenkins as a docker container that I pulled from docker hub with ``docker pull jenkins`` and my jenkins user is not root. How can I install chromedriver from the job executable script?

Answer (score 3):

A simple approach would be to build your custom Jenkins docker image based on the official one.

The structure would be like this:

```
# Dockerfile
FROM jenkins

# Set user root to allow us to install the rest of what's needed
USER root

# <install your stuff here>

# Go back to non-sudo user
USER jenkins
```

I've pushed an image `docker pull elgalu/jenkins` with installed Chrome,  chromedriver and Python3 with Selenium bindings. As you requested.

You can either use my image or check the source code and build it yourself:

https://github.com/elgalu/jenkins-chrome